# iPhone simulator keeps app running on Build and Run

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, iphone-sdk-4.1

I have a problem with my iPhone simulator. Since yesterday when I press Build and run.

- Xcode builds the project
- Simulator closes the running app
- Simulator opens the running app in same state as it closed (multitasking?)

The old build keeps running, I have to quit the simulator before i can run the new build. 
I tried cleaning the project, tested with a new project. Same problem. Rebooted everything.

Running Xcode 3.2.4 / 4.1 SDK.

Comment: What happens if you delete the old app from the simulator, either from within the simulator or from ~/Library/Application Data/iPhone Simulator/{version}/{app ID}?

Comment: no reason why this should be happening. And it shouldn't be doing multi-tasking either because when you build and run it re-installs the program on your device (this instance in the simulator). Does it do this even if you press the stop tasks button?

Comment: Doesn't do it when I remove the app within simulator. But then starts doing it again. And it does it even when I stop first. (works when I stop using doubletap on home btn)

Comment: Tried a new Xcode install. No luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going crazy with the same problem.  It seems that some people have this problem and some don't.  Somehow I stumbled onto this:  http://openradar.appspot.com/8915498

Basically, it says that if you're running the iPhone simulator on a different volume than the xCode app, there is some problem with updating the simulator and you have to restart each time.

I almost ignored the fix because I only use one volume, but I *DO* use filevault for my home folder.  Since the Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator was in my /Users/[me] directory, I guess it's a different volume.

So, what I did was:

1) Go to /Users/[Me]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator and renamed to "old-iPhone Simulator"  (just to get it out of the way without deleting)

2) Go to /Library/Application Support and create a new folder called "iPhone Developer"

3) Open Terminal and enter: `ln -s "/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" "/Users/[Me]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"`

Viola!  Worked like a charm for me!  Now iPhone simulator shows me the changes I make every time I push "Build and Run" without any other hassles!  Yay!
3)

Comment: Thank you, I was going absolutely insane over this same problem. Your fix worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I added a Run Script to my target to work arround the issue

```
killall -9 "iPhone Simulator"
```

Not a proper fix, but works for now.